# UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 62-11168: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python-2.7, text, nlp, summarization, bartender

Help me figure out what's wrong with this. I am running Text summarization using Transformers

~/Bart_T5-summarization$ python app.py
No handlers could be found for logger "transformers.data.metrics"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 6, in 
    from transformers import BartTokenizer, BartForConditionalGeneration, BartConfig
  File "/home/darshan/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/transformers/**init**.py", line 42, in 
    from .tokenization_auto import AutoTokenizer
  File "/home/darshan/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/transformers/tokenization_auto.py", line 28, in 
    from .tokenization_xlm import XLMTokenizer
  File "/home/darshan/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/transformers/tokenization_xlm.py", line 27, in 
    import sacremoses as sm
  File "/home/darshan/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sacremoses/**init**.py", line 2, in 
    from sacremoses.tokenize import *
  File "/home/darshan/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sacremoses/tokenize.py", line 16, in 
    class MosesTokenizer(object):
  File "/home/darshan/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sacremoses/tokenize.py", line 41, in MosesTokenizer
    PAD_NOT_ISALNUM = r"([^{}\s.'`\,-])".format(IsAlnum), r" \1 "

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8wADZ.png)
**UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 62-11168: ordinal not in range(128)**

Answer (score 4):

Running the command with python3 instead of python solved this issue for me. I was able to run the code and obtain a summarization.